# No module named boto3 on EC2 AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am running a script on EC2 based on `ami-0130c3a072f3832ff` 2018.03 version.

In the list of preinstalled packages there is `python-boto3`

But when I try to `import boto3` it says `No module named: boto3`

How can I resolve this issue?

Note: There is a problem, in this situation I can't use the internet (I would have used pip if this was possible)

EDIT1:

- Python 2.7
- Packages checked http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages
- Instance-store backed is used, I don't know if it makes difference using the ebs-backed version.

EDIT2:
I am starting a EC2 instance to run the script on startup and shut down after the execution.

```
instance = EC2.run_instances(
    ImageId=AMI,
    InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='terminate',
    UserData=script
)
```

The script is written in Python and begins with `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Are you using a particular version of python? Boto3 may be installed for 2.7 and not 3 or vice versa.

Comment: By the way, that is an instance-store backed AMI. Are you choosing that intentionally for any reason?

Comment: How did you view the "list of preinstalled packages"? I launched the AMI and couldn't find boto3 on it.

Comment: I've looked up here for packages: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages/

Comment: I choose it accidentally since I thought that in my case it wouldn't matter if it is ebs-backed or instance store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pip and boto3 from the packages available through amazon AMI.

`sudo yum install python-pip python3-wheel
     && Pip install boto3 --user`

- @ljmocic